# Typo3 / Femanager email confirmation autologin not working

Tags: typo3

I'm using Typo3 10 LTS with femanager 6.1.2. Im using PHP 7.4. It is not possible, to login the user after email confirmation. The autologin function doenst work. I checked the checkbox "setCookie" in the extension settings as it was described, but it doenst work.

Does anyone has an idea whats wrong?
Many thanks.